# Show that $X_n\to0$ in probability does not imply $\frac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ in probability, even if the $X_n$ are independent.

Tags: probability-theory

Show that $X_n\to0$ in probability does not imply $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ in probability, even if the $X_n$ are independent.

How to approach this problem. Any hints will be appreciated. I  am not able to even start the problem.

Comment: What if each $X_n$ is either small with high probability, or very large with small probability?